# Unable to apply plugin: 'dexguard' at build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, dexguard

I've below error when I add `apply plugin: 'dexguard'` into my main module's **build.gradle** file.

> Error:Unable to load class
>   'com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$PostCompilationData'. Possible
>   causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - You are using JDK
>     version 'java version "1.7.0_67"'. Some versions of JDK 1.7 (e.g.
>     1.7.0_10) may cause class loading errors in Gradle. Please update to a newer version (e.g. 1.7.0_67). Open
>     JDK Settings
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt
>     (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires
>     network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may
>     be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build processes (requires
>     restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin
>     which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the
>     version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of
>   corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then
>   killing all Java processes.

MY project's **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir dirs: 'C:/Users/devrimtu/Documents/Programs/DexGuard/DexGuard6.1/lib'
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ':dexguard'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
```

My main module's **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'dexguard'

android {
 ..
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')
            proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        release {
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
            proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** If I remove `apply plugin: 'dexguard'` line, error becomes:

> Error:(29, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'getDefaultDexGuardFile()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> - The project 'AndroidWorkSpace' may be using
>     a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Gradle settings
> - The build file
>     may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply
>     Gradle plugin

**Extras:**

I've `DexGuard v6.1`. And the `flatDir dirs` at `build.gradle` file is the correct location.

Android Studio `v 1.3.0 (build 141.2117773)`

Gradle under Android Studio installation dir `gradle-2.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved after updating the DexGuard to version 7.0.18.